# JMeter jp@gc Parametrized controller - construct object from variables

Tags: jmeter, xml-parsing, jmeter-plugins

How to construct an object with attributes taken only from jp@gc-Parametrized controller user defined variables list, that can be used for building dynamically xml/json data structures for HTTP Sampler later on?

Controller variables:
[image]

XML structure for HTTP request body:

Example 1:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <login>
        <username>someUser</username>
        <password>1234</password>
    </login>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saving JMeter variables, so you can use `${}` syntax

```
<userName>${username}</userName>
<password>${password}</password>
```

To get dynamically variables in XML Body use the following sample

```
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
String xmlBody="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><login>";
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(vars.getIterator(), Spliterator.ORDERED), false).forEach(
    e -> xmlBody+="<" +e.getKey() + ">" +e.getValue() + "</" +e.getKey() + ">");
xmlBody += "</login>";
log.info(xmlBody);
```

Comment: The xml structure is not static and has to be build dynamically based on the jp@gc - Parametrized controller UDV list

Comment: @NikolayMarinov AFAIK there isn't a builtin way to dynamically know which variables are defined in the controller

Comment: I assume it can be done via ctx.getVariables(), but not sure how to iterate through it.

Comment: @NikolayMarinov but you have other JMeter variables as `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok`, `START.YMD`, ...

Comment: I hoped that UDV list from jp@gc can be filtered somehow

Comment: @NikolayMarinov added sample to get dynamically variables in XML Body (using inside JSR223 Sampler)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your above [Parameterized Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ParameterizedController/) setup you can refer the declared variables like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<login>
    <username>${username}</username>
    <password>${password}</password>
</login>
```

[image]

Which will result into variables substitution in the runtime with their respective values which can be checked using i..e [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener :

[image]

Check out [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) article for more information on various approaches to JMeter test parameterization.

Comment: Dmitri, what if the input list in jp@gc - Parametrized controller is dynamic?

Comment: Then you can add a prefix or a postfix to it in order to be able to distinguish the variables defined in the parameterized controller from the others. Once done you should be able to build the XML request body dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language. It provides [`sampler` shorthand for HTTPSamplerProxy class](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) instance allowing manipulation of request details.

Comment: So, the jp@gc UDV list is not exposed at all in a form of Map or List to be accessed later on?

Comment: It just adds the defined values to "normal" JMeter Variables: https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/prmctl/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/control/ParameterizedController.java#L31